# Text Alignment changed when window size is changed

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to make it where the percentage text and loading text stays in the middle of the loader when I resize. The width change works when I resize the window, but when I change the height it moves the text. I'm not sure why this is happening but if someone is able to help me under why this is happening that would be nice.

CSS:

```
<style type="text/css">
    html {
        height: 100%;
        width: 100%;
    }
    body {
        background: url("https://cdn.cporigins.com/site/images/bg.jpg");
        margin: 0;
    }
    .container {
    display: none;
        position: relative;
        font-family: 'Do Hyeon', sans-serif;
        font-size: 27px;
    }
    .middle {
        position: absolute;
        top: 50%;
        left: 50%;
        bottom: 50px;
        transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
        text-align: center;
    }

    hr {
        margin: auto;
        width: 40%;
        border: 0;
        height: 1px;
        background: #333;
        background-image: linear-gradient(to right, #ccc, #333, #ccc);
    }
    a {
        text-decoration: none;
    }
    a:hover {
        color: #add8e6;
    }
    i#heart-icon {
        height: 18px;
        width: 18px;
        background-image: url(https://cdn.cporigins.com/site/images/heart_icon.png);
        background-repeat: no-repeat;
    }
    i#heart-icon:before {
        content: "";
        padding-right: 18px;
    }
    .loader {
        font-size: 10px;
        margin: 50px auto;
        border: 16px solid #f3f3f3;
        border-top: 16px solid #6294f9;
        border-radius: 50%;
        width: 120px;
        height: 120px;
        animation: spin 2s linear infinite;
        background-repeat: no-repeat;
        position: relative;
        bottom: -32%;
    }
    @keyframes spin {
        0% {
            transform: rotate(0deg);
        }
        100% {
            transform: rotate(360deg);
        }
    }
    #loadingDiv {
        position: relative;
        top: -50px;
        left: 0;
        width: 100%;
        height: 100%;
        background: #8360c3;
        background: -webkit-linear-gradient(to top, #2ebf91, #8360c3);
        background: linear-gradient(to top, #2ebf91, #8360c3);
    }
    #loaderTxt {
        position: relative;
        color: white;
        font-size: 32px;
        font-family: 'Do Hyeon', sans-serif;
        top: 297px;
        font-weight: bold;
        text-align: center;
    }
    #loaderPercent {
        position: relative;
        color: white;
        font-size: 32px;
        font-family: 'Do Hyeon', sans-serif;
        top: 128px;
font-weight: bold;
        text-align: center;
    }
    </style>
```

I basically have it where it appends the divs to the html tag in js.

```
$('html').append('<div id="loadingDiv"><div class="loader"></div><div id="loaderTxt">Initializing Origins</div><div id="loaderPercent">0%</div></div>');
```

[image: https://i.imgur.com/GhJzX0K.png]

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In these type of design you got to put the container to flex and center all items ( make it relative too )... Now make all items inside it absolutely positioned ... Here all items will come to the center ( of that container )... Viola, You will never get a problem of putting out the elements based on px size ever again..

```css
html {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
}

body {
  background: url("https://cdn.cporigins.com/site/images/bg.jpg");
  margin: 0;
}

#loadingDiv {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background: #8360c3;
  background: -webkit-linear-gradient(to top, #2ebf91, #8360c3);
  background: linear-gradient(to top, #2ebf91, #8360c3);
}

.loader {
  font-size: 10px;
  margin: 50px auto;
  border: 16px solid #f3f3f3;
  border-top: 16px solid #6294f9;
  border-radius: 50%;
  width: 120px;
  height: 120px;
  animation: spin 2s linear infinite;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  position: relative;
}

@keyframes spin {
  0% {
    transform: rotate(0deg);
  }
  100% {
    transform: rotate(360deg);
  }
}

#loaderTxt {
  position: absolute;
  color: white;
  font-size: 32px;
  font-family: 'Do Hyeon', sans-serif;
  bottom: 10vh;
  font-weight: bold;
  text-align: center;
}

#loaderPercent {
  position: absolute;
  color: white;
  font-size: 32px;
  font-family: 'Do Hyeon', sans-serif;
  font-weight: bold;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<div id="loadingDiv">
  <div class="loader"></div>
  <div id="loaderTxt">Initializing Origins</div>
  <div id="loaderPercent">0%</div>
</div>
```

Comment: You know what I tried making the display container flex and it really didn't make any difference. I will try the other stuff you added to it.

Comment: awesome that worked thank you. I just have to fix the loading text though but that's easy

Answer (score 0):

Try to end your css alignment line with !important

so if you want to align this html text

`<p>THIS IS MY TEXT</p>`

You can use css like this

`p{text-align:center !important;}`

I hope this answer helps.

Comment: Doesn't really help. I have the site url in the post if you wanna check out and inspect in developer tools

Comment: This Problem happens when your content gets out of your page body flow.
To solve this issue you have to comment on each section of your page and for sure the problem will be solved, then try to un-comment them again one by one and see which section caused this problem. then when you find it try to solve it.